# Amazon AWS Glacier multi-part upload with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-glacier

I've been struggling to find a simple way to backup my files using AWS Glacier. The documentation is not very explicit:

[Doc 1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/complete-multipart-upload.html)

[Doc 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/api-multipart-initiate-upload.html)

Especially this doc, which is completely useless:
[Doc 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-archive-mpu.html)

Anyone around here has some experience with AWS Glacier?

Comment: You want to specifically use glacier features, such as volts, volts access policies, volt locks? Or you just want to upload a file or directory to glacier storage class in s3? if the later you could  have a look at regular s3 api and its `--storage-class` option  in [s3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html), for instance.

Comment: @Marcin just store into s3 Glacier.

Comment: Then sync should be enough: `aws s3 sync my-local-folder s3://my-glacier-backup-bucket --storage-class GLACIER`

Comment: @Marcin This works! if you put that as the answer I will accept it as the right answer so it not just a comment and you get the credit you deserve

Comment: Nice to hear. Answer added.

Comment: @Marcin done. I add this to validate what you said: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: Found out the hard way: `aws s3 sync` does not work with vaults created with `aws glacier create-vault`. Create your buckets with `aws s3 mb` instead. Apparently the "bucket" name for a vault "foo" is "s3:://vaults/foo" but `aws s3 sync ./bar s3://vaults/foo --storage-class GLACIER` results in `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation`, even with full admin permissions. Other variations of "s3://..." result in `(NoSuchBucket)`.

Comment: @kitchin so what happened? you uploaded your data and then could not retrieve it?

Comment: @user3259176 You can still retrieve it using glacier. The whole `aws glacier` command tree is legacy for me, because `aws s3 sync ... --storage-class GLACIER` works so much better. My pain was that I had forgotten that and not taken notes the first time I figured it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution is to use `s3 sync`, e.g.:

```
aws s3 sync my-local-folder s3://my-glacier-backup-bucket --storage-class GLACIER
```